# Rails UNIQ method not working - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i am trying to use the rails helper method `uniq` but unsure why it is not working. Your help would be much appreciated

- i have a list of application forms eg:3 forms
- 2 of the application forms are by women and 1 is by a man
- The 2 application forms are by the same woman
- `@forms.count` = `3`
- `@forms.female_applicants.count` = `2`
- `@forms.female_applicants.uniq.count` = gives me `2` but the answer should be `1`

> Model

- `Form` belongs to a `user`
- `User` has many `forms`
- `User` belongs to `category_gender`
- `Category_gender` has many `users`

> Form.rb

```
scope :female_applicants, ->() { joins(:category_gender).where('category_genders.name' => "Female") }
```

> **My Question:** If the same woman has 2 forms, could one kindly advise me how to
>   display the number of forms uniquely as 1 rather than 2. so when
>   queried `@forms.female_applicants.uniq.count` the result will be `1`
>   and not `2` if there is a better way than using the `uniq` method i would very much appreciate if told

Comment: It sounds like there may be non-unique elements of you @forms results. If you type `@forms.female_applicants` in the rails console and look at the resulting output you'll probably see pieces of data that are not unique across the collection. Perhaps you can try this and add it to your original question.

Comment: i tried writing something like this `@forms.female_applicants.where(user: user_id).count` but no luck

Comment: This gave the right answer `@forms.female_applicants.group_by(&:user).count` - gave a count of `1` - i may be wrong - any advise would be much appreciated

Comment: Using a scope in Form.rb filters the form records, so female_applicants scope actually returns all form records from female users (and not the users themselves). That's why uniq wasn't working like you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dan & @hypern you were right - there were non-unique elements present which was why i could not use the rails method `uniq`

using `@forms.female_applicants.group_by(&:user).count` resulted in the answer i was looking for

many thanks